# Get session data in Django SessionWizardView

Tags: django, django-views

I am using a SessionWizardView and would like to get information about the currently logged in user.
From what I know, something similar is achieved in a normal view by doing the following:

```
user_profile = (User.objects.get(id=request.session['_auth_user_id'])).get_profile()
```

Since SessionWizardView is supposed to be based on sessions I would expect this to be an easy task but I simply can't find a solution... Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i'm not getting you right, but if you're using the default django authentication system, you can always get the currently logged in user by calling `request.user` (as seen [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests)).

Comment: Yes, I've managed to solve the problem now, it is just as you said, I was simply trying to reach the session at a wrong location... silly me :)

Comment: Can you share your solution, I also need the current user from Session WizardView